# FluentValidation : custom validator factory and client validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, fluentvalidation

I have my own ValidatorFactory with structuremap implementation in asp net mvc 3 application.

```
public class StructureMapValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType) as IValidator;
    }
}
```

And in global asax ...

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => 
{ 
  provider.ValidatorFactory = new StructureMapValidatorFactory(); 
});
```

Well, with this combination client validation doesnt work, if i use standard provider configuration, client validation works fine.

Is here any workaround?

Comment: Read this : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-client-side-validation/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have properly configured your DI framework to resolve the validators. If  `ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType)` returns null, it won't work because there won't be any validator associated to the model and no metadata will be emitted.

Comment: Well, yes in my bootstrap i have explicit registration each fluent validator in structure map, but client validation still not work.

Comment: Did you debug your code inside the Configure method? Did you ensure that `ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType)` doesn't return null? I guess you haven't because IMHO that's the reason your code doesn't work => there's no validator being returned for the given type. Instead of using StructureMap, try at first hardcoding the corresponding validator: `provider.ValidatorFactory = new MyViewModelValidator();`.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, var instance = ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType) as IValidator returns null

Comment: Btw If i set validator manually ([Validator(typeof(validation_class))]) client validation works fine. But I want use DI in my validator class, so how properly configuration my structure map container?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `[Validator(typeof(validation_class))]` with a custom `ValidatorFactory`. As far as configuring StructureMap is concerned that's another topic => you could start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, forgot calling Configure method in my boostrap. So,

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new StructureMapValidatorFactory()));
```

**and then**

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```